# Xcode can't import the app to my phone. No Signing certificate

Tags: ios, xcode

[image]

After upgrading to High Sierra and Xcode 9, I want to test the app on a different phone. Maybe my certificate expired. [image]

Comment: Create a developer account and create your certificates . https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/MaintainingCertificates/MaintainingCertificates.html

Comment: I have a free account. I just want to test it on the phone.

Comment: Choose signing certificate in tour project . You will se your certificate in a dropdown

Comment: I have tried it. It didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by deleting the DerivedData folder and rebuilding the project. Then I restarted my computer (this will start a prompt that asks you for password when you start Xcode). I entered my login password and clicked on Always Allow. You have to click on Always Allow or it won't work.